# Authenticate directory structure in apache

Tags: php, apache

I want to know how we can authenticate directory structure in apache by scripting.

Note: authenticate user if he pin up to directory structure means ask his login password if he is authorized or not.

Mean: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13139411  suppose user enters this in browser then exist structure should ask for authentication.

Comment: what do you mean disable directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about [this kind of authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) (and you're using Apache), you need to set up users with `htpasswd` and then configure your .htaccess file for basic authentication.

Take a look at the [Getting it working](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking) section on the above link.